# do-release-upgrade ubuntu 10.04 always failed

Tags: do-release-upgrade

i was trying this tutorial(https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades#SpecificOlder) to upgrade Ubuntu 10.04, but always failed. 
source.list

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

i execute the command : `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`
 the last display on terminal is :

```
Restoring original system state
Aborting
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done
```

During upgrading, there are some error when loading 
[Failed Read Mirror File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUrKs.png)

and error

```
 Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid-security/universe Packages
    Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid-security/multiverse Packages
    Err http://archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/main Packages
      404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
    Fetched 0B in 0s (0B/s)
```

i dont know where **archive. ubuntu. com** come from, there is no on my source.list

i also follow this solution (askubuntu. com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release), but not work on me, the error still occur

Any solution? thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/q/91815/308164)

Comment: i was follow this solution, but not work on me

Answer (score 1):

Can you test if your internet connection is IPv6 ready with http://www.test-ipv6.com? Maybe that's the problem. If you can't connect via IPv6, then try the following:

```
1. In Terminal, type "pkexec gedit /etc/gai.conf"
2. Uncomment (i.e. remove "#" at the beginning) the line "precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100"
```

After that, IPv4 connection should be used and upgrade process should work.

Comment: yes, maybe the problem in IPv6. i try uncomment "precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100", then i execute "do-release-upgrade", the problem still exists. Then i try execute "lynx http://www.test-ipv6.com/" the output is "
Looking up www.test-ipv6.com
Making HTTP connection to www.test-ipv6.com
Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host.
lynx: Can't access startfile http://www.test-ipv6.com/ "

Answer (score 1):

Others have found that the update reports an authentication problem, and lists all the packages that were unauthenticated, then does a rollback.

According to this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1513232

there's a bug where the 12.04 packages appear to be unauthenticated to the do-release-upgrade. The bug report includes a couple of potential workarounds. The one suggested in the original report worked for me.

Comment: While I didn't see the message "Error authenticating some packages" in the output from do-release-upgrade, the workaround mentioned in the link you provided also worked for me.